# Wordpress wp_list_pages highlight current page

Tags: wordpress, highlight, custom-post-type

I using this:

```
<ul>
    <?php wp_list_pages("&post_type=projects&child_of=$parent_page&title_li="); ?>
</ul>
```

To get that:

```
<ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-588"><a href="#" title="One">One</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-592"><a href="#" title="Two">Two</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-599"><a href="#" title="Three">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

First code should display list of child pages.
Everything is fine, But i faced with some problem. If i used custom post type (like `projects` in example), Wordpress 3.2.1 can't add  "current" class to `<LI>` and i can't highlight random opened current page.

functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_projects' );
    function register_cpt_projects() {
    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Проекты', 'projects' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Проект', 'projects' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Добавить', 'projects' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Добавить проект', 'projects' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Изменить', 'projects' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'Новый Проект', 'projects' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'Просмотреть', 'projects' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Поиск проектов', 'projects' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'Ничего не найдено', 'projects' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Ничего не найдень в корзине', 'projects' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Родительский Проект:', 'projects' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Проекты', 'projects' ),
    );
    $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats', 'page-attributes' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page'
    );
    register_post_type( 'projects', $args );
};
```

variable
$parent_page:

```
   // get_top_parent_page_id
    function get_top_parent_page_id($id) {
        global $post;
        if ($post->ancestors) {
            return end($post->ancestors);
        } else {
            return $post->ID;
        }
    };
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 6):

wp_list_pages() will compare the current page to menu items and add class "current_page_item" to the li containing link to current page.

All you need to do is add

```
li.current_page_item{
/*your specific mark up here */
}
```

to your style.css file in the theme folder. No need to modify functions.php

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages#Markup_and_styling_of_page_items

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way will be to consider using `wp_nav_menu` instead of `wp_list_pages` - it is much more flexible solution and can do what you want. You'll have to sync the menu with the list of your pages, but it can be done automatically using actions.

Answer (score 1):

in functions.php add this

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'current_type_nav_class', 10, 2 );
function current_type_nav_class($classes, $item) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ($item->attr_title != '' && $item->attr_title == $post_type) {
        array_push($classes, 'current-menu-item');
    };
    return $classes;
}
```

Source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12292/11610

Answer (score 0):

Solve it with no pain and just body class :)

In functions.php:

```
function get_id_outside_loop() {
    global $wp_query;
    $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
    return $thePostID;
}
```

In header.php:

```
<body class="<?php echo get_id_outside_loop(); ?>">
```

In `<head>` sections or in footer.php:

```
<STYLE>
<!--
body.<?php echo get_id_outside_loop(); ?> .project_pages ul li.page-item-<?php echo get_id_outside_loop(); ?> 
{
  background: #0096f4; /* Highlight */
}
-->
</STYLE>
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your functions.php:

```
function kct_page_css_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) {
  if ( !isset($args['post_type']) || !is_singular($args['post_type']) )
    return $css_class;

  global $post;
  $current_page  = $post->ID;
  $_current_page = $post;
  _get_post_ancestors($_current_page);

  if ( isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors) )
    $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
  if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
    $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
  elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
    $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';

  return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'kct_page_css_class', 10, 5 );
```

Via http://kucrut.org/wp_list_pages-for-custom-post-types/